# AOT Query relation OR case

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

For example I have the following x++ query.

```
Select EcoResproduct
   join tableX
       where EcoResproduct.RecId == tableX.Product
          || EcoResproduct.RecId == tableX.DistinctProductVariant;
```

Is that possible to do the same thing through **AOT query** without using a union query or adding two times the same datasource and without using QueryBuildDataSource object and X++ at all .

Thanks in advance

PS: I made my question more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Initial incorrect answer:**

> Is that possible to do the same thing through an AOT query without using a union query or adding two times the same datasource

No.

**Correct answer, thanks to the commenters:**

```
Query q = new Query();
QueryBuildDataSource qbds1 = q.addDataSource(tableNum(EcoResproduct));
QueryBuildDataSource qbds2 = qbds1.addDataSource(tableNum(TableX));

qbds2.addrange(fieldNum(TableX, RecId)).value(strFmt('((%2.Product == %1.RecId) || (%2.DistinctProductVariant == %1.RecId))', qbds1.name(), qbds2.name()));

info(qbds1.toString());
```

Comment: I agree that this is the right answer, but for fun, there *may* be a way to hack it via expressions in query ranges. @nikos Kou would need to screw around with the syntax for a while, but it may be possible? http://www.axaptapedia.com/Expressions_in_query_ranges https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/using-expressions-in-query-ranges . It never looks pretty though.

Comment: I cannot see how I can do this with ranges since is an "OR" relation between two tables.

Comment: Use `((Product==EcoResproduct.RecId)||(DistinctProductVariant==EcoResproduct.RecId))` as range value in the tableX datasource.

Comment: @JanB.Kjeldsen, you are right, for some reason I decided that would work for ranges but not for joins... I suggest you to create a *new*, correct answer next time rather than provide a correct answer in comments as it is not that user-friendly to those who might be looking for a similar solution in future.

Comment: @JanB.Kjeldsen This is work if you build a query through X++, I would like to do the same only if I build a query through AOT and not through X++

Comment: @Nikos Kou, have you tried it? It should work regardless of the way the query has been created.

Comment: Is working!!! My problem is that if onother developer for unknown future reason will change the name of the datasource in the query  then the query is not working correctlly. 

In any case I will keep in mind @JanB.Kjeldsen solution.