# D365 AOT Query OR Condition

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, aot

First off, I have alread read these two articles:

[AOT Query relation OR case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53006273/aot-query-relation-or-case)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/using-expressions-in-query-ranges?redirectedfrom=MSDN

In AX2012, you could use parentheses to create complex query range expressions that would allow OR statements and for interacting with multiple fields.  This no longer seems to work in D365.

In this example, I am attempting to write simple OR statement on a query range that will use a like expression on a warehouse name or the warehouse ID.

This is the range value expression I am using:
((InventLocation.Name == "*Fin*") || Inventlocation.InventLocationId == "*11*"))

Even if I simplify this to a single expression without an OR, it does not work.  The query returns no results.  The only expressions I can get to work are the simplest *Fin* works or *11* works, but nothing more than that.

[image: Expression in Query Range]

Comment: did you see SQL code behind this query?

Comment: I know you can do that with a View.  Is there a way to do that with an AOT query?

Comment: you can init a query with this AOT query like query  q = new Query(queryStr("myQuery")) then with using info see the value.