# How to use 'LIKE' in queryBuilder in AX 2012

Tags: sql-like, dynamics-ax-2012

I am new to QueryBuilder and was trying to convert the below select statement which contains `like` into a query, but I am not able to do that.

Can anyone please help me with the same?

```
while select * from dummyTable
  where dummyTable.Field1 Like 10* || dummyTable.Field2 Like 10*
```

Below is my queryBuilder code:

```
qbr = qbds.addRange(fieldNum(dummyTable, Field1);
qbr.value('10*');

qbr = qbds.addRange(fieldNum(dummyTable, Field2);
qbr.value('20*');
```

The above piece of code is returning:

```
SELECT * FROM DummyTable(DummyTable_1)
WHERE ((Field1 LIKE N'10*')) AND ((Field2 LIKE N'20*'))
```

I need `OR` operator instead of `AND` in the above statement. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53006273/aot-query-relation-or-case) which produces an `OR` relation. Please update your question if you cannot get it to work. Side note: make sure to check if the AX kernel translates the AX `*` wildcard to the proper SQL `%` wildcard. Use `SysQuery::valueLikeAfter` as shown [here](https://www.tech.alirazazaidi.com/advance-filter-dynamics-ax-2012-similar-to-like-wildcard-functionality/) if the wildcards are not properly handled (I do not have an AX2012 environment at hand to verify right now).

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood correctly. Following our *community contributor*, please, could you check and stydy the code below.

```
static void Job1(Args _args)
{
Query query;
QueryRun queryRun;
QueryBuildDataSource dataSource;
QueryBuildDataSource dataSource2;
QueryBuildDataSource dataSource3;
str textDesc = "";

query = new Query();
dataSource = query.addDataSource(tableNum(LogisticsAddressCountryRegionTranslation));
dataSource2 = dataSource.addDataSource(tableNum(Currency));
dataSource2.relations(true);
dataSource3 = dataSource2.addDataSource(tableNum(LogisticsAddressCountryRegion));
dataSource3.relations(true);
SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(dataSource, fieldNum(LogisticsAddressCountryRegionTranslation, LanguageId)).value("EN-US");

if (textDesc != "")
{
    SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(dataSource, fieldNum(LogisticsAddressCountryRegionTranslation, ShortName)).value(SysQuery::valueLike(textDesc));
}

info(query.dataSourceNo(1).toString());
queryRun = new QueryRun(query);
}
```

LIKE command

```
 SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(dataSource, fieldNum(LogisticsAddressCountryRegionTranslation, ShortName)).value(SysQuery::valueLike(textDesc))
```

OR command, could you

```
static void WIK_LikeNotLike(Args _args)
{
CustTable               custTable;
Query                   query       = new Query();
QueryRun                queryRun;
QueryBuildDataSource    qbds        = query.addDataSource(custTable.TableId);
QueryBuildRange         qbr         = SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(qbds, fieldNum(CustTable, AccountNum));
str                     range       = strFmt('((AccountNum LIKE "%1") || (!(AccountNum LIKE "%2")))',
    SysQuery::valueLikeAfter('C904029'),
    SysQuery::valueLikeAfter('C'));

qbr.value(range);

info(range);
info(qbds.toString());

queryRun = new QueryRun(query);
while (queryRun.next())
{
    custTable = queryRun.get(tableNum(CustTable));
    info(custTable.AccountNum);
}
}
```

Helpful links:

https://stoneridgesoftware.com/programmatically-create-queries-dynamics-ax-data-surprises/

https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/microsoft-dynamics-ax-forum/148751/how-to-join-using-querybuilder/337061

https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/microsoft-dynamics-ax-forum/223431/query-with-or-and-not-like

Find you way.